# Accessing Jquery Key/Values in Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I have a simple form and I need to access the key/value and properties of the jquery code for the form. Also when I try to create a customer in my view with request.form['stripeToken'] it gives error mentioned at end of question. I need to access following fields in Jquery script with key/value attributes:

```
$("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
$("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
```

Following is the code:

Jquery Code:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/yearly" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
<input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'pk_test_YgHVTCLIMQLW4NV6ntnJPAXs',
image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
locale: 'auto',
token: function (token) {

$("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
$("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
$("#myForm").submit();
                    }
                });

$('#customButton12').on('click', function (e) {
      handler.open({
      name: 'Yearly',
      description: 'Yearly Charge',                            
      amount: 9500
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
          $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                    handler.close();
                });

                </script>
```

Following is the view:

```
@app.route('/yearly', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def yearly_charge():


    key = stripe_keys['publishable_key']
    data = get_profile_data(session['auth_token'])       
    profile_data = data['Student']
    student_id = profile_data.id
    student = get_profile_data(session['auth_token'])['StudentProfile']    
    pkg = Package.query.filter_by(student_id=profile_data.id).first()
    # customer
    stripe_token = request.form['stripeToken']
    email = request.form['stripeEmail']
    if not pkg:

        try:
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email,
                source=request.form['stripeToken']

            )
            print request.form
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=customer.id,
                plan="yearly",
            )
            student_id = profile_data.id
            student.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
            student.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
            package = Package(
                student_id=student_id,
                stripe_id = customer.id,
                student_email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
                is_active=True,
                package_type='yearly',
                subscription_id=subscription.id
            )
            dbase.session.add(package)

            dbase.session.commit()

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            # The card has been declined
            body = e.json_body
            err = body['error']
        flash("You've successfylly subscribed for annual package.")

    return redirect(url_for('new_template', key=key))
```

Error:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError
InvalidRequestError: Request req_AMbjoYEtQR1d6Y: Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'
```

Comment: Did you assign the key to the stripe instance anywhere? Like stripe.api_key =key

Comment: I don't get your point. Stripe token is derived from the key association at first place. I can subscribe and even cancel subscription using simple button using this link. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/flask. Things get messed up when I tried for custom button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to implement custom button for stripe. There is an easy way instead of going to write all the code if you don't know how to communicate between python and js.

```
<form action='/yoururl' method='post'>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
               data-key="{{ key }}"
               data-description="Your Description"
               data-amount="500"
               data-locale="auto"></script>
               <input type="submit" value='Subscribe' class='btn' style='height:33px;width:50%;color:white;'>
               </form>
               <script>
document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
               </script>
```

What actually happened in the code is it hides the default stripe button. So then any input button will work for you inside  tag. You can use multiple buttons such as if you have another button you can use different price or other variables and just change the script like below:

```
 <script>
document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[1].style.display = 'none';
               </script>
```

If there is a third button you can do it like:

```
        <script>
document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[2].style.display = 'none';
               </script>
```

Comment: But how would stripe checkout.js script will know which button reflects with what form?

Comment: That's a wrong question. Computer reads data up to down and left to right. First try it and let me know about result.